# Laravel protected $loginView load the default login view

Tags: laravel

I am trying to login for different types of users

but I have an error starting the login view for a certain type of user

laravel default login view loads and not the one i created and assigned to protected $loginView

I cannot understand what is happening, what is the error that occurs?

Web.php:

```
    Route::group(['middleware'=>'web'], function (){
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');


});



Route::get('admins/login','adminController@showLoginForm');
Route::get('admins/login','adminController@login');
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
});
```

adminController:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class adminController extends Controller
{

   use AuthenticatesUsers;
   protected $loginView = 'admins.login';



}
```

admins >login.blade.php:

```
<form method ="POST" action="">

<label for="email">Email:</label>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email">

<label for="pass">password:</label>
<input type="text" name="pass" id="pass">

<button>login</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, there is no `$loginView` property that Laravel utilizes to determine which view should be used for the login page, so why do you believe that it should work?

[Here](https://github.com/laravel/ui/blob/master/auth-backend/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L19) is the `showLoginForm` method:

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    return view('auth.login');
}
```

So what I would suggest you do is the following, remove the `$loginView` property and overwrite the `showLoginForm` method:

```
class adminController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('admins.login');
    }
}
```

PS:

Why do you have the route `admins/login` with the method `get` twice?

```
Route::get('admins/login','adminController@showLoginForm');
Route::get('admins/login','adminController@login');
```

You probably meant to use `post` for the second one.